# django-livereload-server not working 404 Not Found

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, livereload, django-livereload-server

I'm using Django 2.0.2, and I want to reload my static files live. i followed these instructions:

https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server
yet when I do

```
python manage.py livereload
```

and access `localhost:35729`  i get `404: Not Found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to execute

```
python manage.py runserver localhost:8000
```

and then, in other bash execute (same directory):

```
python manage.py livereload
```

then access to your project through localhost:8000 in your browser

Comment: thank you ! i figured this out 2 days later hhhhhhhhhhhh